# Rating make star fill on hover

Tags: html, css

How can I make the star appear as filled when you hover and click 
So I need it to be like this unfilled at first:
[image]

And if you hover to fill out and if you click it to be filled like in the photo:
[image]

This is what I have tried so far

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}


.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f006";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}



/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
<h1>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

...

As you can see it is using fontawesome icons so for unfilled it is \f006 and for filled \f005

Comment: Bit confused, Are you trying to fill star on hover ?

Answer (score 1):

Please do check, i have updated the code and its looking fine.

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}


.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f006";
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}



/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
<h1>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Everything works fine. But how to get the rated values during a form submit?

Comment: After form submission, getting post data.
For ex: if you select 4 star rating then it will take value 4.